# What is correct time format for YAML objects in context of Jekyll

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll

The format `yyyy-mm-dd` parses the string into a Date object, but `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm` does not (it keeps it a string). If some dates are parsed as Date object and some are parsed as strings, this field is not accepted for `sort` function.

My date/time fields are not in the front matter, just in some object that is defined as part of front matter.

Are there any formats that also include time and are parsed into a Date object? (ideally, without having to specify seconds and time-zone info; I would also not mind if Jekyll never converted my date/times into Date object but I don't know how to ensure this)

Answer (score 1):

To format a DateTime you will need to include the seconds to match the YAML spec for [timestamp](https://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html)

> A timestamp value represents a single point in time. This can be serialized using a subset of the ISO8601 format and the formats proposed by the W3C note on datetime. In addition, a more relaxed format is also supported for enhanced readability, using white space separation.
>
> If the time zone is omitted, the timestamp is assumed to be specified in UTC. The time part may be omitted altogether, resulting in a date format. In such a case, the time part is assumed to be 00:00:00Z (start of day, UTC).

Jekyll uses `SafeYAML` for parsing and you can see the regex used [Here](https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml/blob/master/lib/safe_yaml/parse/date.rb#L11)

```
DATE_MATCHER = /\A(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\Z/.freeze

TIME_MATCHER = /\A\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}(?:[Tt]|\s+)\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d*)?\s*(?:Z|[-+]\d{1,2}(?::?\d{2})?)?\Z/.freeze
```

[Examples](https://rubular.com/r/YzSHVeIPZg8QtA)

So for your data to work correctly you can format as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (using `strftime` formatting `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`); however please note that this will be assumed to be UTC if no zone is specified.

There are likely other ways like notating the object via `"!ruby/object:DateTime"` but it is probably easiest to just conform to the YAML spec instead.

Comment: I think I had also tried `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, but this still produced a string, not a Date object (at least if failed sorting along with other Date objects). But I'll retry in case I missed something!